# Sim card reader + Linux +MC8705

Tags: linux, pci-express, sim, fit-pc

I am looking at using the PCI-E MC8705 from Sierra Wireless in FIT-PC2. The MC8705 does not have a sim card slot, but rather expects there to be a USIM card interface.

Are there linux drivers for supporting such cards by way of usb sim card readers? Or any good mini pc boards with onboard sim card readers that I could use instead of the fit-pc2?

Answer (score 1):

Mini PCI-x modem are meant to have a sim socket on the carrier board. There are pins reserved for that on the mini PCI-x connector. As for the driver, contact Sierra Wireless rep. and they will provide it to you. In fact' I'm planning on installing this device on my design.